# How to delete vectors pointer to object, when vector is in inner class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to delete fully vector which contains references to pointers.

I HAVE found thread in stackoverflow about this, but I have a little bit different situation, which, I am sure, will benefit others when they read this question.

I have inner class in my class, in order to hide implementation of initialization and variables. Because of that, I have to create pointer to vector, when I am trying to operate with it. Here I have written method of how to completely delete these objects from vector and clean vector itself:

```
   void Program::deleteAll(){
      vector<Category> *ptr = &(impl->categories);
      vector<Category>::iterator it;
      for (it = ptr->begin(); it != ptr->end(); ){
         delete *it;  
         it = ptr->erase(it);
         it++;
      }
   }
```

The poblem is here: delete *it. I get an error here. How to delete objects, which are stored as pointers to objects, in this cycle? I can sho wyou, how I put objects to vector categories:

```
   void Program::addCategory(string name){
      vector<Category> *ptr = &(impl->categories);
      Category cat(name);
      ptr->push_back(cat);
   }
```

Comment: Is `Category` a `typedef` for a pointer? If not, then you shouldn't be deleting it.

Comment: @juanchopanza: And if it is, it should be changed to a typedef for `shared_ptr`, and still not manually deleted.  But from `Category cat(name);` we can see that it isn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Not really, no. I have to delete them in order to delete objects fully, otherwise, objects are left without deletion after destructor is being called and completed, which is not a good deal!

Comment: You only have to delete them if they are pointers to dynamically allocated objects and it is your job to delete them. It looks like you don't have to delete anything. Just call `ptr->clear();`

Comment: @Fractal: You only `delete` what you created with `new`.  You haven't created anything with `new` here.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I will talk about this in greater detail tomorrow with my lecturer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
void Program::deleteAll()
{
   impl->categories.resize(0);
}
```

The destructor for each `Category` object will be called by `std::vector`, so any pointers inside `Category` will be cleaned up.